# How to upload only images in GWT fileUpload

Tags: gwt

I need to  upload one image file into my application. I am using GWT 
FileUpload compontent to  upload the File. But when I use FileUpload,
the FileUploadDialog displayed All files.. I need to set it
only for image files . How can I set filter for that?

Thanks,

Ajinkya.

Comment: What effort have you made so far? And what difficulty you are having at that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML <input> has accept Attribute  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

do like this on GWT

```
FileUpload upload=new FileUpload();
upload.getElement().setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
```

Comment: Its working  ... thnx, but i want to remove that all file option also. Is it possible?

Comment: According to http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.file.html attribute "accept" can accept as a value the list of MIME types and "Provides the UA [user agent] with a hint of what file types the server is able to accept."

"All files" default option in drop down list is provided by browser, not by source page.

Look also here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input for list of Mimetypes that is supported by FF. It depends on UA implementation how the specific browser is going to support 'accept' attribute.

The answer is no, it's not possible.